how to get text from an object in seleniumbase?
seleniumbase launches a browser, opens a page, and enters a query into the search box. Then follows the links in a loop. And then in each link at each iteration of the loop, tries to pull h3 out of the link:
def rel_prods(url, one_data):
with SB(headed=True, uc=True) as driver:
    driver.open(url)
    time.sleep(26)
    driver.type('#header-search', one_data['title'])
    driver.click('button[data-auto="search-button"]')
    time.sleep(random.uniform(2, 6))
    elements = driver.find_elements('a[data-auto="snippet-link"]')
    i = 1
    for element in elements:
        try:
            h3_tag = element.get_text('h3')
            print(h3_tag)
            element.click()
            time.sleep(2)
            driver.switch_to_window(i)
            time.sleep(random.uniform(2, 6))
            driver.close()
            driver.switch_to_default_window()
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)

And that's where the error comes out:
'WebElement' object has no attribute 'get_text'

Who knows how to implement this?
And also the driver.close() command closes the browser completely. I would like it to close only the current tab

Could you explain what you mean by "tries to pull h3 out of the link"?

but it gets all links from the page with the attribute data-auto="snippet-link" on the line elements = driver.find_elements('a[data-auto="snippet-link"]')
And then there's an h3 tag in each of those links

So you probably want something like element.find_element_by_tag_name('h3').get_text.

find_element_by_tag_name it's a method from classic selenium. It is not available in seleniumbase

I'm not familiar with seleniumbase. .find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'h3')?

You are asking at least 3 questions in this one question which is not allowed on Stack Overflow. Q1: How to get text from an object in seleniumbase? Q2: How to get the text from the H3 under the A tag you've found. Q3: How to close only the current tab? The question title is Q1 so that's what I've answered. If you want your other questions answered, you'll need to post a new question with the relevant details, a [mcve], error messages, etc.

The error message
'WebElement' object has no attribute 'get_text'

is telling you that there is no method .get_text() on a WebElement, e.g.
element.get_text('h3')

is not valid.
What you want is
element.text


Thank you! You've solved a major problem. The other issues were not so important)
